# Recursive regular expression in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I have a script that open a request to a server and gets a javascript output.

this output looks like this:

> html = new Array();mark = new Array();html.push('html tags(something i want)more html');mark.push(new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312));html.push('html tags(something i want)more html');mark.push(new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312));html.push('html tags(something i want)more html');mark.push(new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312));html.push('html tags(something i want)more html');mark.push(new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312));html.push('html tags(something i want)more html');mark.push(new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312));OtherStuf.idontcare(new Object(-16.630495852614, -49.264667191591), 13);

i want to create a regular expression to take everything in: `(something i want)` and the numbers on `new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312)`, so in this part:

> html.push('html tags(something i want)more html');mark.push(new Obj(-12.1231231, -12.12312312312))

i want to get only:

```
(something i want)
-12.1231231
-12.12312312312
```

but this for every place i find this.

i created this regex to take all the inner content

```
/^html = new Array\(\);mark = new Array\(\);(.*)OtherStuf.idontcare\(new Object\([\+\-\.0-9]*, [\+\-\.0-9]*\), [\d]*\);$/
```

but now i'm kinda of stuck. i cant see any way of taking the info that i need.

how can i do this?

gist with my regexp and a example of the javascript i need to parse: https://gist.github.com/NicosKaralis/5571240

Comment: are you trying to write a regular expression that can parse html markup? if so then it is impossible.

Comment: It appears to be something to re-write a jumbled snippet of JavaScript.

Comment: i dont want to parse html markup, i want to parse this js, which contains some html markup, but only some points of it

Comment: I am saying that you cannot parse non-regular syntax with regular expressions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language. You can find a hack that works most of the time, though, for your specific input data.

Comment: but the js i want to parse is like that, is regular. the things that are not regular are the things i need to slice and use

Comment: @akonsu is right: this string contains self-embedding.
RegExp are only useful on languages on type 3 (see Chomsky definition).
You can split the string through a regexp and then on each chunk apply a single regexp linke this one: `/html tags\(([^\)]*)\).*new Object\(([^,]*),([^,]*)\)/`

Answer (score 0):

a single regex can't handle want you want.

I recommend that you first split into blocks and then run a regex on each of them:

```
output.split(/html\.push/).each do |block|
  # grab "something i want" and the numbers in block
end
```